# Create an iterative counter in DJango template

Tags: javascript, html, django

I've checked a lot of other questions and I haven't seen my particular scenario really addressed and I've tried a lot of things out without success.

What I have is a DJango for loop in my HTML code, and within the for loop is an if statement checking if each element from the list that is being looped through equals a certain value. If that is true, then an entry is created on the page. I need to dynamically print the element number (eg. entry 1 would display as 1. and entry 2 would display as 2.)

The two best attempts I have made are:

1.

```
<!-- this approach prints out 1 for each entry -->
{% with counter=0 %}
{% for q in questionnaire.questions %}
         {% if q.answer %}
         <div class="row"><h3>
                 {{ counter|add:1 }}. {{ q.name }}
         </h3></div>
         <!-- some other code-->

         {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

2. 

```
{% for q in questionnaire.questions %}
         {% if q.answer %}
         <div class="row"><h3>
                 <span id="displayCount">0</span>. {{ q.name }}
         </h3></div>
         <!-- some other code-->
         {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the view, you can do the filtering in the view, and then make use of `{{ forloop.counter }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the built-in counter of your for loop using `forloop.counter`. It starts at `1`, you can also you `forloop.counter0` if you'd like to start at zero.

```
{% for q in questionnaire.questions %}
         {% if q.answer %}
             <div class="row">
                 <h3>
                     {{ forloop.counter }}. {{ q.name }}
                 </h3>
             </div>
             <!-- some other code-->
         {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Filter your queryset in your view as to avoid issues with indexing and separating presentation from logic.

Comment: This was my first idea as well, but this will also increment if `q` is not an `answer`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem made a suggestion to filter in the view and then not have to worry about the loop. Great idea!

Comment: Hi @Harben I did try using forloop.counter and ran into that issue of not working if the if statement evaluates to false. I'm pretty new to this so could you explain what you mean by filtering in the view? Thank you!

Comment: @sabeernarula filter your queryset in your view function or CBV before passing to your template.

Comment: Awesome, will give it a go and update. Thanks for your help!